# SQL Server Standard High Availability (HA) with two nodes

Tags: sql-server, failover

Is it possible to accomplish High Availability (HA) with two SQL Server Standard nodes ?

- We can't use SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn without Groups as it has single point of failure by using the "single" database file
- We can't use SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn with Groups because it's placed in Enterprise package and we don't have license for that
- We can use any other SQL Server version but in Standard packaging level
- We can't use mirroring because it requires a third SQL Server used as witness server

Any other suggestions ? I have tried to find an answer all over the internet and didn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Log Shipping is another option.

Comment: What's the problem with having a third instance as witness in mirroring?

Comment: Witness server requires additional license and VM, we have third VM that we can use but maybe it's to weak for SQL Witness server. Thoughts ?

Comment: The witness can be an Express Edition, unless they've changed things. And there's no real processing/storage overhead imposed by acting as a witness.

Comment: +1. Witness basically can be a very small instance using Express - it doesn ot really do anything except standing there and be a witness ;)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that SQL Express is an option and that it doesn't require much resources. We will try Express and see if that will be the solution for us. BTW thanks for the one that migrated this to dba stackexchange :)

Comment: Beside witness server is there any option with two nodes ? We will check the log shipping as I'm not fully familiar with that approach, does it work in HA - sync & failover ?

Comment: One more thing. Witness server with database mirroring is not mandatory. If you consider possibility to fail over manually, you only need two SQL Server instances. However installing small express instance for free is more secure option. Moreover, if the secondary server is passive-only, then you don't need separate license for it.

Comment: Well my environment is Azure, so I'm trying to overcome the host update scenario (which happens almost every month) so I'm seting up HA environemnt with two SQL Servers in one availability set (as client have licenses for this) and, as suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever, SQL Express server as witness server. But with that setup I may have one more potential issue, my witness server is Azure Small instance and I can't scale it to XL instance like other servers so what are my options here? What happens when host update occurs and witness server is down ?

Comment: We have manage to get everything up and running with SQL Express, one thing that is an issue right now is when witness server is restarted the witness service won't auto start and that leaves the secondary SQL server hanging when primary is down, any ideas ?

Comment: It turns out that simple auto start delay and different account did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Database Mirroring. Witness node is optional.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190941.aspx

You may configure a failover cluster with virtual shared storage. There are guys who do the VSAN for Windows (however they call it "for Hyper-V" but don't get confused it works bare metal on Windows as well).

http://www.hotwebclips.com/Home/Show/tGgqG8oEpBQ

Comment: What happens to auto switching from secondary to primary mirroring node ? This happens automatically only when witness server is running or ?

Comment: You don't need witness for failover. Also if your RTO/RPO are flexed out enough you may look @ Hyper-V Replica as it does support SQL Server (with some limitations for the scenario usage).